# NavMeshAgent in Unity giving jerky performance

Tags: unity, path-finding, navmesh

I am using NavMeshAgent in my Unity project to calculate and move my object to a particular location.

When I do:

`navMeshAgent.destination = destinationPt`

the object starts moving, but the motion of the object is very jerky.

Is there a way to override the function which is responsible for the jerkiness of the object motion? Or is there a way I can remove the jerkiness of the motion some other way?

I also tried setting

`navMeshAgent.updatePosition = false`

after which I use

`navMeshAgent.CalculatePath(destinationPt, path)`

to get the path, but then after this I am not able to figure out how to write my own logic to make the object move. I want a smooth motion with a given acceleration and a max velocity.

Answer (score 3):

Your camera movement is jerky, not the movement of your object.

When updating the camera position it's best to use [`LateUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html), this ensures that the update takes place after all of the other [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) calls. This means the position of the camera will be accurately positioned for the same frame you're updating. As stated in the documentation:

> For example a follow camera should always be implemented in LateUpdate
>   because it tracks objects that might have moved inside Update.